# Inter-module dependencies dependent on config possible in SBT?

Tags: sbt

I'm attempting to scope a dependency to a module in the same project using SBT's configurations.

In production, this dependency is satisfied by a jar on the classpath, but during dev it would be nice to do `server/config-a:run` or `server/config-b:run` to select the dependency manually.

Currently, I have something like this:

```
lazy val configA = config("config-a") extend Runtime
lazy val configB = config("config-b") extend Runtime

lazy val DevConfigA = Project(id = "dev-config-a", base = file("dev-config-a"))
lazy val DevConfigB = Project(id = "dev-config-b", base = file("dev-config-b"))

lazy val server = Project(id = "server",
                          base = file("server"),
                          dependencies = Seq(common))
                      .configs(configA, configB)
                      .dependsOn(DevConfigA % configA, DevConfigB % configB)
```

DevConfigA and DevConfigB bring in resources used for configuration. We want exactly one of them to be loaded. The goal is that `server/config-a:run` would depend on DevConfigA module, and not DevConfigB.

I had to move the `configs` and `dependsOn` out of the call to `Project.apply` to get it to compile. After that, the `DevConfig*` dependencies aren't showing up when I `server/config-a:run` or if I call `show server/config-a:dependency-classpath`.

Is there a way to make inter-module dependencies dependent on the config?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's a way to make dependencies configuration-dependent - use `libraryDependencies` config-scoped.

I'm using the latest stable release of SBT.

```
[server]> show sbtVersion
[info] 0.13.1
```

Let's assume you need different versions of a library, e.g. scalaz, based upon what configuration you execute `run` with. As a matter of fact, you don't have to worry about the task, but the dependencies available in a given configuration, and since `libraryDependencies` drives it, I'm going to use it.

```
[server]> help libraryDependencies
Declares managed dependencies.
```

Here's the `build.sbt` that gives what you want.

**build.sbt**

```
lazy val configA = config("config-a") extend Runtime

lazy val configB = config("config-b") extend Runtime

lazy val server = project in file(".") configs(configA, configB)

val scalaz705    = "org.scalaz" %% "scalaz-core" % "7.0.5"
val scalaz710_M5 = "org.scalaz" %% "scalaz-core" % "7.1.0-M5"

libraryDependencies in configA += scalaz705

libraryDependencies in configB += scalaz710_M5
```

With the above `build.sbt` sbt lets us pick different versions of Scalaz based upon configuration.

```
[server]> show libraryDependencies
[info] List(org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.3)
[server]> show config-a:libraryDependencies
[info] List(org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.3, org.scalaz:scalaz-core:7.0.5)
[server]> show config-b:libraryDependencies
[info] List(org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.3, org.scalaz:scalaz-core:7.1.0-M5)
```

Comment: Anyway to do this with module dependencies instead of libraryDependences? In my example, DevConfigA and DevConfigB are other sub-modules.

Comment: Could you add to your question the definitions of the submodules? When you use `DevConfigA % configA` it means `compile->configA` that in turn means that `compile`-scoped libraries from `DevConfigA` end up as `configA`-scoped libs. Is this what you're after?